# Coarse quotient maps

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coarse-geometry

Interesting connections and analogies have been observed between
non-linear geometry of Banach spaces and coarse geometry.
In the former subject, people have investigated the notion of
uniform (or Lipschitz) quotient maps. See, e.g., [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1736929).
The corresponding notion for coarse geometry is coarse quotient maps.
We say a map $q\colon X\to Y$ between metric spaces is a **coarse quotient map**
if $\exists K>0$ $\forall R>0$ $\exists S>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ one has
$q(B(x,R)) \subset B(q(x),S)$ and $B(q(x),R) \subset N_K(q(B(x,S)))$.
Here $B$ denotes the ball and $N_K$ denotes the $K$-neighborhood.

When $G$ is a countable discrete group with a proper left invariant metric,
every quasi-morphism $q\colon G\to {\mathbb R}$ is a coarse quotient map.
In fact, I view a coarse quotient map from $G$ to ${\mathbb R}$
as a metric analogue of a quasi-morphism.

I wonder if coarse quotient maps are worth studying.

Here's a sample question: Does $\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ admit
a coarse quotient map to ${\mathbb R}$?

Added: This notion has been studied in Sheng Zhang
Israel Journal of Mathematics volume 207, pages 961-979 (2015) ([ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1934), [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-015-1168-6), [MR link](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3359724)).

Comment: A remark. Clearly a map $X\to Y$ satisfying $q(B_X(x,R))=B_Y(q(x),R)$ satisfies the condition, and composing with QIs preserve the conditions. In particular, for every infinite finitely generated group with word length $|\cdot|$, the map $g\mapsto |g|$ is a "coarse quotient map" $G\to \mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: (Sorry my last comment was senseless, I erased it)

Comment: And my first (non-erased) comment was too hasty too: there might be "dead ends" in a finitely generated group and the the condition can't fail. However if a group is QI to a metric space in which any two points belong to a bi-infinite geodesic, it works. This applies at least to cocompact lattices in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ for $n\ge 2$.